# Using multiple api calls with set state under UseEffect with one dependency, how to prevent extra re render of child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React world, I'm struggling to prevent extra rerender of child stateless component, but no luck here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Lab from "./components/Lab";
import RecentlyCreatedWo from "./components/RecentlyCreatedWo";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import WoCount from "./components/WoCount";
import Wostatus from "./components/Wostatus";
import ApiService from "../../common/utils/ApiService";
import { ApisConfig } from "../../common/configuration/api-config";
import localStorageService from "../../common/utils/localStorageService";
import { Year } from "../../common/utils/Year";
import { Dropdown } from "primereact/dropdown";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState(2021);
  const [woCount, setWoCount] = useState(null);
  const [recentWo, setRecentWo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const api = new ApiService();

    api
      .get(
        ApisConfig.SomeAPi +
          "?someId=" +
          localStorageService.get("userLoginData").someId +
          "&year=" +
          selectedYear
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setWoCount(res);
      });

    api
      .get(
        ApisConfig.someOtherApi+
          "?someId=" +
          localStorageService.get("userLoginData").someId+
          "&year=" +
          selectedYear
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setRecentWo(res);
      });
  }, [selectedYear]);

  const onYearChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedYear(e.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="admin-dashboard">
      <div className="p-grid">
        <div className="p-col-8">
          <Dropdown
            optionLabel="key"
            value={selectedYear}
            options={Year}
            onChange={onYearChange}
          />
          <Wostatus data={woCount} />
          <RecentlyCreatedWo data={recentWo} />
        </div>
        <div className="p-col-4">
          <WoCount data={woCount} />
          <Lab />
          <Users />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I have obsereved here is everytime when the year changed including first time render, my child component recieve props three times, I know this is happen because useEffect is being called on setState event and year change event.

What I need is child compenent should rerender when the api call finished and props are updated, what is the best way of achieveing this functionality and optimize the logic ?

Comment: use `Promise.all` and then in the callback, set your state

Comment: put woCount & recentWo to one state

Comment: yeah just like [state,setState] = useState({woCount, rencentWo});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting answer to my own question for any newbie who could struggle just like me.

For such issues, react functional component has useMemo() hook, for my problem, I have sloved it by using the hook like this.

```
   const woStatus = useMemo(
    () => (
      <p>
        <Wostatus data={data.woCount} />
      </p>
    ),
    [data.woCount]
  );
```

And than in JSX part we can simply initialize child component like

```
{Wostatus}
```

This blog has helped me to understand the actual issue and the solution available in react itself.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Answer (score 0):

everytime we do setSomething, react rerenders the childs,
no matter even if you do like this

```
const data1 = await fetch();
const data2 = await fetch();
setData1(data1);
setData2(data2);
```

update your react version to 18, it batches the setState hooks.
https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

Comment: fyi, its in alpha now. the last stable is 17.0.2

Answer (score -1):

You can set the state after all api calls finish, its alos beetter to use single state for both values, so instead of separate `woCount` and `recentWo` you can use and object `{ woCount, recentWo }`:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({ recentWo: null, woCount: null })

useEffect(() => {
    const api = new ApiService();

    api
      .get(
        ApisConfig.SomeAPi +
          "?someId=" +
          localStorageService.get("userLoginData").someId +
          "&year=" +
          selectedYear
      )
      .then((recentWo) => {
        api
        .get(
          ApisConfig.someOtherApi+
            "?someId=" +
            localStorageService.get("userLoginData").someId+
            "&year=" +
            selectedYear
        )
        .then((woCount) => {
          setData({ recentWo, woCount })
        });
      });
  }, [selectedYear]);
```

For more readability you can change to async/await:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({ recentWo: null, woCount: null })

const fetchData = async () => {
  const api = new ApiService();

    const recentWo = await api.get(
        ApisConfig.SomeAPi +
          "?someId=" +
          localStorageService.get("userLoginData").someId +
          "&year=" +
          selectedYear
      )
    const woCount = await api.get(
          ApisConfig.someOtherApi+
            "?someId=" +
            localStorageService.get("userLoginData").someId+
            "&year=" +
            selectedYear
    )
    setData({ recentWo, woCount })
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [selectedYear]);
```

Comment: no it's same, setRecentWo rerenders the child and SetWoCount again rerenders the childs. but with your solution delay between rerenders just dropped off by some amount.

Comment: Updated the answer, so that only one setState is called

Comment: Yup!! and what about selectedYear dependency, now it will be render 2 times which doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: from what I see, selectedYear, should not cause additional re-renders

Comment: yeah, react-18 is the only solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: @varaprasadh, unless you put your states into single object - yes.

Comment: selectedYear changes, triggers useEffect and that makes API calls and again setWoCount something, which in turn rerenders the child.

Comment: @NikitaMazur agreed, we can batch the data.

Comment: @varaprasadh, yes, but its intentional, so if `selectedYear` does not need to be the trigger for api call, just remove it from useEffect deps

Comment: @NikitaMazur when selected year changed the api call is needed for that year of data.

Comment: Exaxtly, so just put `woCount` and `recentWo` into a single object `{ woCount, recentWo }` and set it after all api calls are finished.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply, I have tried above solution i.e putting woCount and recentWO into single object, and selectedYear as a dependency of useEffect, but now also it is rendering the component two times.

Can't use react 18 as it is in alpha mode so using 17.0.2, can somebody give me a workaround.